# AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver error

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-mvc, locale

I have defined "localeResolver" bean in Spring configuration file as

```
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="language" />
</bean>
```

User hits this URL to change locale `/setLocale.do?language=fr` 
But I am getting exception `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:` before this method is called. In order to solve it I have to use **`SessionLocaleResolver`**

Is there anyway that I don't have to use `SessionLocaleResolver`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the implementation of `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` and think about its name for a bit.

https://github.com/bbossgroups/bbossgroups-3.5/blob/master/bboss-mvc/src/org/frameworkset/web/servlet/i18n/AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver.java

> Note: Does not support setLocale, since the accept header can only be changed through changing the client's locale settings.

`AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` will resolve the `Locale` from the request (using the accept header) and that's it. There is no way to set its locale property to any different value. If you need the locale to be changeable your stuck with `SessionLocaleResolver`. There's always to option to write your own resolver if the existing ones don't suit your goal.